# How to store Views templates with a module instead of a theme

Tags: views, theming

I have created several views templates that are currently stored in my active themes directory.  In would prefer these templates be stored within my module directory.

My question is, how can I bring these theme files (views-view-field.tpl.php for example.) into my modules directory and have them be seen by Views?

Looking at the Views modules, I can see that default templates are stored in views/theme, but I don't see how it has been implemented.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This took me a while to figure out as well. The following code should be placed in your .module file (the code assumes your module is called "NAME")

```
/**
* Implements hook_views_api().
*
* Enabling using templates inside module
*/
function NAME_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'NAME'),
    'template path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'NAME'),
  );
}
```

This will tell Views to look in the root directory of your module. I personally am a fan of adding a subdirectory to the module to hold template files. To do this append the directory name to the end of the template path, eg:

```
'template path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'NAME') . '/templates',
```

Comment: Adding them to a sub-directory is a fantastic idea, cleans things up and it works perfectly.  Future searchers make sure to clear your Drupal cache.  Thank you @Reekan Mantell

Comment: Thank you! I've been hacking my admin theme for months just to over-ride a views field in seven. Now I don't have to.

Comment: And I must say that you can still put TPL in your theme even if you have implemented this code. Thanks.

Comment: This will not work with Features modules, instead use `hook_views_api_alter()` as noted here: https://www.deeson.co.uk/labs/views-templates-features-module

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to define the template using 'hook_theme', as this article describes: http://grayside.org/2010/09/how-override-views-field-template-module

Answer (score 2):

If the above examples will not work in **Drupal 8** try this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function MODULENAME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'views_view_grid__dashboard__page_1' => [
      'template' => 'views-view-grid--dashboard--page-1',
      'base hook' => 'views',
    ],
  ];
}
```

**OR**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function MODULENAME_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  // Override view template in module, not in the theme
  $theme = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getName();
  if ($theme == 'adminimal_theme') {
    $theme_registry['views_view_grid']['path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULENAME') . '/templates';
  }
}
```

But note that MODULENAME_theme_registry_alter works only once after cache clear and can not be usable in some places

**views_view_grid** is the template name in your templates folder